# Chrome Dictionary Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want a chrome extension that does this: When I select a word and right click on it I should get the option of searching that word in Collins Dictionary website. chatGPT recommended this.

background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Search Collins Dictionary",
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: searchWord
  });
  
  function searchWord(info, tab) {
    const word = info.selectionText;
    const url = `https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/${encodeURIComponent(word)}`;
    chrome.tabs.create({ url });
  }
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Collins Dictionary Search",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Search for a word in Collins Dictionary.",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"]
}
```

and content.js is empty

this code doesn't show anything when I right click.